# InertiaJS Manual Visits - Full Page Refresh In Some Cases & Partial Reloads not working properly

Tags: reactjs, laravel, page-refresh, inertiajs

I've started working on a Inertia SPA Project (Laravel-React) recently in which I have a lot of pages, routes and controllers. Things seemed to work just fine until I found this issue.

In Some Pages, I update my models' data using **useForm** to handle state and post and in Laravel I return Inertia redirect response which works as expected (refreshes partially as a SPA should).

On the other hand, on some pages when I use *the same* **useForm(post)** or **router.post** with all necessary parameters to delete or update my models, a **full page refresh** happens (which shouldn't as far as I know);

I'm trying to understand why and whether It's my error or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was a bit confusing but for those might have similar issue with InertiaJS :

If you experience any problem, make sure you have migrated to newest version. Specifically, those who use InertiaJs (laravel + react) might have trouble with partial loading and full page refresh which was bug in versions below 1. As of now that version 1 is introduced and fully debugged for that matter, it is safe to use for such projects with no hassle.

Additionally, using Vite in your flow might have some positive impact for those create such projects.